# M.2 SATA SSD not found by ASrock B450m pro

Tags: sata, m.2

For the life of me I can't get my motherboard to recognize that there is a SATA stick in the M.2 slot of my ASRock B450m Pro4. This is an entirely fresh build, I'm unsure if there are special steps for M.2 installations that I'm simply missing.

> Specs:
>
> [ASRock B450M PRO4](http://asrock.pc.cdn.bitgravity.com/Manual/B450M%20Pro4.pdf) (Bios 1.20)
>
> RYZEN 5 2600 3.4 GHz
>
> 16GB (2x8GB) DDR4 DRAM 3000MHz
>
> [WD Blue 3D NAND 500GB SATA M.2 WDS500G2B0B](https://www.wd.com/content/dam/wdc/website/downloadable_assets/eng/user_manual/4779-705170.pdf)
>
> ASRock Phantom Gaming X Radeon RX 580 8GB

Comment: There is a huge difference between SATA M.2 and NVMe M.2 are you positive your motherboard supports SATA M.2 the manual only specifically calls out boot NVMe.  **M2_2 and SATA3_3 share lanes. If either one of them is in use, the other one will be disabled**

Comment: I'm a doof.
@Ramhound, it supports both types, I bought SATA and not NVME.

Comment: @K7AAY I was reviewing the QVL storage docs, and I plugged it into the wrong m.2 port

Answer (score 1):

The motherboard slot M2_2 is for the slower SATA M.2 drive you have, per the STORAGE section on page 4 of your [ASRock manual](http://asrock.pc.cdn.bitgravity.com/Manual/B450M%20Pro4.pdf) linked above. Page 7 has a diagram which shows the positions of the two M.2 slots.  Also, SATA cable connector SATA3_3 blocks the use of the M2_2 slot; please make sure any optical or other drive is not on SATA3_3.

Answer (score 0):

I too experienced this issue.  And I think the fine print in the manual is that the 2nd slot only recognizes SATA drives, and NOT M.2 drives.

Comment: The distinction you are looking for is SATA vs PCIe.  All of them are "M.2"

Comment: Exactly right Ben Voigt

Comment: This seems to repeat the existing question

Answer (score 0):

The Manual states:

```
"•   1 x M.2 Socket (M2_2), supports M Key type
2230/2242/2260/2280 M.2 SATA3 6.0 Gb/s module**
** Supports NVMe SSD as boot disks
** Supports ASRock U.2 Kit"
```

---Very unclear writing.---

The Brochure states:

```
4 SATA3, 1 Ultra M.2 (PCIe Gen3 x4), 1 M.2 (SATA3)
```